# PHP Exceptions CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, exception

my code is generating ssse following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   CI_Exceptions::show_exception() must be an instance of Exception,
>   instance of Error given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gog\lib\core\Common.php on line 662 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gog\lib\core\Exceptions.php:190 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gog\lib\core\Common.php(662):
>   CI_Exceptions->show_exception(Object(Error)) #1 [internal function]:
>   _exception_handler(Object(Error)) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\gog\lib\core\Exceptions.php on line 190

The line of the codes described is these:

```
    function _exception_handler(Throwable $exception)
{
    $_error =& load_class('Exceptions', 'core');
    $_error->log_exception('error', 'Exception: '.$exception->getMessage(), $exception->getFile(), $exception->getLine());

    // Should we display the error?
    if (str_ireplace(array('off', 'none', 'no', 'false', 'null'), '', ini_get('display_errors')))
    {
        $_error->show_exception($exception);   //line 662

    }

    exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
}

public function show_exception(Exception $exception)  //line 190
    {
        $templates_path = config_item('error_views_path');
        if (empty($templates_path))
        {
            $templates_path = VIEWPATH.'errors'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        }

        $message = $exception->getMessage();
        if (empty($message))
        {
            $message = '(null)';
        }

        if (is_cli())
        {
            $templates_path .= 'cli'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        }
        else
        {
            set_status_header(500);
            $templates_path .= 'html'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        }

        if (ob_get_level() > $this->ob_level + 1)
        {
            ob_end_flush();
        }

        ob_start();
        include($templates_path.'error_exception.php');
        $buffer = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        echo $buffer;
    }
```

Someone can pinpoint my problem ?

Comment: the `$exception` variable is not an instance of `Exception` (Seeing your declartion, it's an instance of `Throwable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `show_exception(Exception $exception)` from within `_exception_handler(Throwable $exception)`. Since the former takes an `Exception` as argument, you cannot give it a Throwable, as you do in line 662. Exception implements the Throwable interface, but that does not guarantee all Throwables to be Exceptions (e. g. they could be of type `Error`).

Replace `_exception_handler(Throwable $exception)` with `_exception_handler(Exception $exception)`, or change `show_exception(Exception $exception)` to `show_exception(Throwable $exception)`, and change the method bodies accordingly if needed.

Comment: Additionally you might want to change the parameter name from `exception` to `throwable` if it is of type Throwable, as this improves readability and does not confuse the reader to have a different type than they expect.

Comment: The code in question is part of CodeIgniter itself. OP is not supposed to ever touch it.

Answer (score 1):

No CodeIgniter version has that `_exception_handler()` signature. This is what happens when you modify stock framework files.

Download a fresh copy of the latest CodeIgniter and replace yours with it.